# Problem using ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE/DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE with file path

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I'm trying to use ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE/DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE with file paths on SQL Server MS 14. I'm able to encrypt a given file path but when I try to decrypt I get a NULL value

I have already played with the types of the parameters without any change in the result. I tried to cast/convert the encrypted result to varbinary without success

```
select ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('stackoverflow', 'C:\Users\brogeli\Documents\Personal\select-network-option.pdf', 1, 
CONVERT(varbinary, '10'))


SELECT  DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('stackoverflow', 
'0x010000005A331BC5AE1C1A7E3BDD47249768C5F51029970883DEEEED65457C7DC87EC0A020241BE11C45145850C2AA79078CD97E0704728262F825C92DC8E58C7A586A3B7EE798E435167F7DDC500706032A3F88707D5A13D88AF0A7B6DA309261F41CB56CFDE42A0DE0AC7B'
, 1, CONVERT(varbinary, 
'10'
));
```

I expect to get the same file path with all characters but the actual output is NULL

EDIT:
So I tried this and it worked

```
select cast(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('stackoverflow',
0x01000000BD9C213B8C9B279BA9B91E152EB9E8B37F3E37F4E4C4FAD4E104C706642B87C40838E65CA4AF7DF8276F191F04AF691C9753DB6C304D0F5733CCCD76A803A2AA7DCD3D6E9B4BDD19BE7B403DA9940B49CED28D414CCA0640D772E413DEF21B51BA343BEA3F6A10AA, 
1, CONVERT(varbinary, '10'))as varchar(8000));
```

however, my idea is to create two stored procedures to encrypt/decrypt and pass the encrypted result as varchar to the decrypt procedure, so I tried cast/convert to varbinary but this doesn't work:

```
select cast(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('stackoverflow',
cast('0x01000000BD9C213B8C9B279BA9B91E152EB9E8B37F3E37F4E4C4FAD4E104C706642B87C40838E65CA4AF7DF8276F191F04AF691C9753DB6C304D0F5733CCCD76A803A2AA7DCD3D6E9B4BDD19BE7B403DA9940B49CED28D414CCA0640D772E413DEF21B51BA343BEA3F6A10AA' as varbinary), 
1, CONVERT(varbinary, '10'))as varchar(8000));
```

any ideas on how to accomplish this? Pass a varbinary as a varchar and cast/convert back to varbinary

Comment: Does it work for non-filepath cleartext?

Comment: nope I tried already

Comment: OK, so the question has nothing to do with file paths, really..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
SELECT @@VERSION;

declare @b varbinary(max);
declare @pass nvarchar(200) ='stackoverflow';
declare @aut varbinary(max) = CONVERT(varbinary,'10');

SELECT @b = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE( @pass, 'C:\Users\brogeli\Documents\Personal\select-network-option.pdf', 1, @aut);
SELECT cast(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE( @pass, @b, 1, @aut) as varchar(max));
```

Output

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB4019093) ...

C:\Users\brogeli\Documents\Personal\select-network-option.pdf
```